# What's the difference between encoding Collect and Array data as json using json_encode() in Laravel - php?

Tags: php, json, python-3.x, laravel, collections

While trying to json_encode some data of type collect() and array() in laravel - php, returns similar json object. On decoding (python - third party API) it differentiate anything?

But after encoding as json, both look like same

```
{"type":"collection","data":[{"id":3,"id_ref":32},{"id":4,"id_ref":43}]}

{"type":"array","data":[{"id":3,"id_ref":32},{"id":4,"id_ref":43}]}
```

Code for encode:

```
json_encode(['type'=>'collection','data'=>collect($array)])

json_encode(['type'=>'array','data'=>$array])
```

Comment: In this context, there is now difference. What `collect()` gives you is an object with a lot of helper methods for handling the array. But when encoded to json, it will work the same. If you just want to json encode an array, passing it to `collect()` will only give you overhead with no benefit.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, Yes, on encoding it's same. but on decoding does it differs?

Comment: No. Since they produce identical json strings after being encoded, they will be identical when decoded. PHP only sees the string for what it is, a string representation of json data. And since they are identical, PHP wouldn't be able to know how to decode them differently, even if it wanted to.

Comment: In this case both `$array` and `collect($array)` are same while encoding as json.